# Why are computer PSUs so large and heavy whereas phone chargers weigh barely anything anymore?

Tags: power-supply

I've noticed that phone chargers have gotten a lot smaller and lighter over the years, to the point where they weigh barely anything. The power supplies that you put in a PC still weigh 2kg. What prevents the improvements in phone chargers to be used for computer power supplies?

Comment: Why aren't locomotives the same weight as a pushbike?

Comment: Pick two example devices (that you have or from datasheets). Add in their power rating (watts) and their weights (kg) and calculate the power/weight ration (W/kg). If there is a large discrepancy then you can ask why.

Comment: A locomotive weighs 2500x as much as a human+pushbike, but produces 25000x as much horse power. The same isn't true of phone chargers versus computer PSUs. Computer PSUs actually have lower power/weight ratio.

Comment: For example, the PSU I have here is 500W for 2kg and the phone charger I have here is 18W for 25g.

Comment: A human on a pushbike can push 2 horsepower. A human / pushbike will weigh about 0.1 tonnes. A locomotive weighs about 100 tonnes and produces about 2000 hp. Given a bit of hand waving, this is the same ratio.

Comment: I have here a PSU from a server that weighs in just under 1 kg and is rated for 950 W, in other words, outperforms your example phone charger in W/kg.

Comment: A human on a pushbike can push 2 horsepower only for a few seconds. A locomotive can push for hours. I took this locomotive: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GE_AC6000CW. The server PSU is interesting. So desktop PSUs could be made small and light, but that's more expensive to do? Do you know what makes it more expensive? Do they need special materials or is the production process difficult?

Comment: See my response.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could build a 2kw supply in a space about 1/20th of the volume and it would cost 10x or more as much because of cost of additional processes to build a PCB and components expense related to smaller components.

Comment: Great question @jules I was wondering the same thing since I built a mini ITX computer and most of the weight is just from the PSU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, the PSU I have here is 500W for 2kg and the phone charger I have here is 18W for 25g.

I would like to start by pointing out that your premise is false: just because the two supplies you give as example show a phone charger having a higher power-to-weight ratio, does not mean this is always the case, and most definitely does not mean that it has to be the case for some underlying limitation of power supplies. See below for an example of what is possible when size or cost is important.

In a phone charger, as a customer you probably want something small and light - you do not want to have a big block to move around all day. This means that the size of that charger is to some extent important for the engineers designing it, and they will make design choices to get the size down: they may choose to go for more expensive but smaller (and lighter) capacitors, for example.

In a consumer desktop computer power supply, size is not a main specification - cost is. Size is often limited by the standards (for example, ATX) anyways, so there is no point optimizing further. As a result, designers will make choices to lower cost, and as a result may elect to use bigger, cheaper capacitors, use less efficient and larger but again cheaper heatsinks, etc.

Thermal management is a second problem: the area for the supply to dissipate scales more slowly than the volume, so as you go higher in power, it becomes more challenging to fit everything in and keep it all cool.

In servers, size is a constraint - we want to fit as much server in as little datacenter as possible. As a result, their supplies tend to feature much, much higher power densities. Take for example the FSP1200-50ERS, a 1200W redundant power supply unit, which is actually comprised of 2 1200W supplies and a ''combining'' frame. One of these two 1200 W supplies weighs in at about 1 kg, giving us a power-to-weight of 1.2W/g. If you compare that to the ''low'' 0.72W/g that your phone charger gives, it is clear that your initial assumption (''power supplies for computers have lower power density than the supplies for phones'') is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, the PSU I have here is 500 W for 2 kg and the phone charger I have here is 18 W for 25 g.

That's 250 W/kg for the large unit and 720 W/kg for the small one.

While this makes the phone charger look much better there are a few other factors to take into consideration:

- The metal case of the large unit adds weight.
- The multiple output voltages required by PCs requires separate secondary windings, rectification, smoothing and regulation on each rail.
- The wiring harnesses add weight.

Comment: Add to that the fact that weight and size is not as much of a concern in many computer PSUs since they are going to go into fixed positions and have a standardized size.

Comment: I doubt the big PSU's case is a larger percentage of its weight than the phone charger. It might be metal but surface area scales as length squared, whereas the weight scales as length cubed. The phone charger also includes a wall socket plug. I would expect there to be economies of scale. For instance a Tesla has 76200000x as much horse power as a toy car. At this rate the toy car would have to weigh only 0,028g to have the same power/weight ratio, so there are huge economies of scale. Why is it so opposite for the PSU? Maybe it's indeed the separate voltages?

Comment: Economy of scale generally applies to cost, not neccesaraly weight. As said earlier, there are less requirements on volume for a computer supply (in general, server supplies are a different matter). As a result you would like to use cheaper capacitors in the latter, which may be bigger and heavier than the more expensive counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, the PSU I have here is 500W for 2kg and the phone charger
>   I have here is 18W for 25g.

Most likely, that phone charger is a cheap one that doesn't meet UL standards by skipping sufficient isolation barriers (tapes, fabrics, metals), running hot (lower wire gauge with lower safety margin), using a thinner shell (less fire/explosion resistance), and sub-reg non-polarized AC contacts (less weight, smaller size).

Also, those charger specs are probably fiction (25g, 18W) -- the Apple charger (~50g, 10W) is more than double that weight and about half that output power.

Comment: I don't know if the specs are fake or maybe my kitchen scale is off by a factor of 2 because I weighed the Apple charger and it says 26g. So if the Apple charger is actually 50g then the other one is also 50g? Though we might be talking about a different Apple charger because this one also says 5V,1A.